# Regular expression to match optional end of string

Tags: java, regex

Given the following:

```
"John Smith"
"John Smith (123)"
"John Smith (123) (456)"
```

I'd like to capture:

```
"John Smith"
"John Smith", "123"
"John Smith (123)", "456"
```

What Java regex would allow me to do that?

I've tried `(.+)\s\((\d+)\)$` and it works fine for "John Smith (123)" and "John Smith (123) (456)" but not for "John Smith". How can I change the regex to work for the first input as well?

Comment: You can also go greedy `^([^(\r\n]+)(?:\((.*)\))?`

Comment: @revo that does not seem to work. In "John Smith (123) (456)", it captures ""123) (456", which is not what I want.

Comment: Yes you are right: [**`^([^(\r\n]+$|.*(?:\((.*)\)))`**](https://regex101.com/r/hI0eS1/2)

Comment: That doesn't work either. In "John Smith (123)", I want to capture "John Smith" and "123".

Comment: Then you need to wrap `.*` in parentheses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may turn the first `.+` lazy, and wrap the later part with a non-capturing optional group:

```
(.+?)(?:\s\((\d+)\))?$
   ^ ^^^           ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI0eS1/1)

Actually, if you are using the regex with `String#matches()` the last `$` is redundant.

*Details*:

- `(.+?)` - Group 1 capturing one or zero characters other than a linebreak symbol, as few as possible (thus, allowing the subsequent subpattern to "fall" into a group)
- `(?:\s\((\d+)\))?` - an optional sequence of a whitespace, `(`, Group 2 capturing 1+ digits and a `)`
- `$` - end of string anchor.

A [Java demo](http://ideone.com/2mXjTZ):

```
String[] lst = new String[] {"John Smith","John Smith (123)","John Smith (123) (456)"};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)(?:\\s\\((\\d+)\\))?");
for (String s: lst) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        if (m.group(2) != null)
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
}
```