# Regex: add to group only if no specific patter found

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a rather trivial pattern but still cannot figure it out.

Imagine, we have a string with "words" split by underscores. Sometimes the sequence can end up with a specific keyword with a follow-up number ("kw#"). Example:

- "foo_bar_omega"
- "bar_omega_kw1"
- "alpha_betta_foo_bar_kw15"

I need the regex that will place the sequence of the words in one group and the keyword with the number into another group.

I've tried:

```py
regex = '(?P<grp1>[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z]+)*)(_(?P<grp2>kw\d+))?'
```

but it places the `bar_omega_pw` in the `grp1` and nothing into `grp2`.

I can also try to match only the keyword with the `regex='(_(?P<grp2>kw\d+$))?'` and after simply split the initial string to identify the `grp1`, but it looks like over-complication.

Is it possible to do the job in one regex go?

What if this pattern is surrounded by other characters, i.e:`123_bar_omega_kw1_&&`?

###### Edit

The question was closed with the "repeated question" flag and referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713165/regular-expression-to-match-optional-end-of-string). While one can get some idea/direction from the suggested old question, here, I believe, we have a little different situation: the pattern of the 1st group "catches" part of symbols that are supposed to be in the second group.

I think that the good answer here would contain an explanation of the importance of using anchors (`^`/`$`) for such types of problems.

Comment: Maybe `\b(?P<grp1>[a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)*?)(?:_(?P<grp2>kw\d+))?\b`? Or `^(?P<grp1>[a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)*?)(?:_(?P<grp2>kw\d+))?$` will do?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. It seems like even this `(?P<grp1>[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z]+)*)(_(?P<grp2>kw\d+))?$` will work. But could you explain?

Comment: You need to "anchor" the pattern using zero-width assertions to make the pattern match some whole entity (a word or string).